# iterating over beautifullsoup items

Tags: python-3.x

I'm relally new in python and its libraries.

For a course in my university, I analyze data from newspapers. I use python and beautifullsoup for it. But now, I'm facing following problem:

I have a list of strings, some belong together, some not.
it looks like:

```
overline
header 
text
overline 
header
header 
text
text
overline 
header 
text
...
```

all things after an overline belong together, they have the same topic.
all items are stored in the same list

I want to iterate over this list and save in a data-warehouse (sqlite)
For each database-entry, I want to combine with the belonging overline. For each header, I want to combine the belonging text.

But how can I solve this problem using my bs4.element.ResultSet?